# "Martin Schkreli has been arrested" -- is the sentence present perfect?

Tags: passive-voice, present-tense

I have been learning the 12 English tenses. The above sentence confused me. The sentence was a headline of a news website. It is kind of like present perfect but not. Present perfect is subject + has/have + past participle. It looks like present perfect progressive but not. Present perfect progress is subject + has/have + been + present participle.

It is not present perfect because of the word "been". It is not present perfect progressive because it doesnt have a present participle.

So my question is what tense is the above question?

Comment: It is the Present Perfect with the passive voice. Someone **has arrested** Martin. --->>> "Martin **has been arrested**".

Comment: @CopperKettle oh, I havent learned about passive voice with tenses yet. Is there any resources for that? Is there any simple rules to remember?

Comment: @CowperKettle mistakes have been made...

Answer (score 1):

The basics of the passive is to remember that you form it by using *be + past participle*. Its use allows to put the focus in the action and not who performed it. In the case of the present perfect, the structure changes to *been + past participle.*

For further information, check [here](https://www.ego4u.com/en/cram-up/grammar/passive).